# Reset local source tracking to latest source tracking in scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx

I am using this command to reset the local and remote source tracking `force:source:tracking:reset`. I am including the `--revision` parameter to reset source tracking to a specific revision number of an org source member. My question is:

**How can I reset my local source tracking to the latest source tracking in my scratch org?**

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_tracking_reset), I need to query the  [SourceMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm) object to figure the correct [RevisionCounter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm), this part I get; however, it is not clear if I need to query the highest [RevisionCounter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm) or the latest [SourceMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm) record.

For example:

Shall I get either the first item of this query

```
SELECT RevisionCounter FROM SourceMember ORDER BY RevisionCounter DESC
```

or get the first item of this query?

```
SELECT RevisionCounter FROM SourceMember ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Comment: you can run `force:source:tracking:clear` before running `force:source:tracking:reset` with specific revision

Comment: I tried this, now my local changes are not tracked locally :(

Answer (score 1):

So,

`sf project reset tracking -p` command would set local files to match the remote source tracking. So there would be no changes to deploy.

`sf project delete tracking -p` command would just delete local tracking files, which means everything should be deployed now.

If instead we would like to reset remote tracking, we could use the following script:

```
for OUTPUT in $(sf data query -q 'select id from SourceMember' -t --json | jq '.result.records[].Id' -r)
do
    sf data delete record -t -s 'SourceMember' -i $OUTPUT
done
```